# Why is the same number printed more than once when trying to generate several different random numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I wanna make 6 different & random numbers in Python.

So I coded it like this:

```
from random import *

def make_lotto():
    n = randrange(1, 46)
    return n

lotto = []
while True:
    if make_lotto() != randrange(1, 46):
        lotto.append(randrange(1, 46))
    if len(lotto) == 6:
        break
lotto.sort() 
print(lotto)
```

Although I defined `if make_lotto() != randrange(1, 46)`, the same number is still printed more than once.

I think `if make_lotto() != randrange(1, 46)` code is not defined.

How could I revise this code?

Comment: Are you trying to generate random numbers without duplicates?

Comment: yes,sir tha's what i meaned,sry my poor eng

Comment: Try `m = randrage(); if not m in lotto: lotto.append(m)`

Comment: `lotto = sorted(random.sample(range(1,46), 6))` to get a list without duplicates.  `random.sample` chooses from a  population without replacement.

Answer (score 0):

> `if make_lotto() != randrange(1,46)`

The numbers generated by the expressions on both sides are random, so, `make_lotto() != randrange(1,46)` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The conventional way of doing something like this is to make an empty list and keep filling the list (under the conditions) until it is complete.

So, you could do this:

```py
import random

r = []
while len(r) < 6:
    x = random.randrange(1,46)
    if x in r:
        pass
    else:
        r.append(x)

print(r)
```

result (random list that keeps changing):

```
[44, 16, 14, 27, 11, 34]
```

Comment: Yes, that's what they already tried to do. The problem was *the condition*.

Comment: the *condition* is satisfied with `len(r) < 6` and `x in r` in this particular case.